# Active record caching solution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there any good gem for record caching for rails 3.2 ?. I tried using record-cache and cache-money bother of them are incompatible with rails 3.2. Is there any other good record-caching gem/mechanisms which works well with rails 3.2. It will be helpful if it is transparent to application with minimal changes in the code.

Regards,
Rajesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check RailsCasts http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=18 videos for Rails caching and check dalli gem https://github.com/mperham/dalli for memcached.

New Relic videos for caching http://www.bestechvideos.com/2009/03/21/railslab-scaling-rails-episode-8-memcached

Answer (score -1):

Do you need to use a gem? Take a look at this [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html).